# Sass map produce variable names

Tags: css, variables, dictionary, sass

I have a map in Sass with keys and values

```
 $colors: (blue: #0081d2, green: #288600, orange: #e57323);

 @each $color, $value in $colors {
    .#{$color} {
        color: $value; 
    }
 }
```

This works and gives me css classnames with the appropriate values, like:

```
 .blue{
    color: #0082d1;
 }
```

What is would like to have is a function that produces sass variables based on the keys in the map.

```
 $blue:  #0082d1;
 $green: #288600;
```

I have been breaking my head but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to return the value by the key specified.

**Example**

```
$colors: (blue: #0081d2, green: #288600, orange: #e57323);

@function color($color) {
    @return map-get($colors, $color);
}

.bacon {
  color: color(blue);
}
```

Results in

```
.bacon {
  color: #0081d2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a map is to have data structured in a more hierarchical way and not just as a bunch of variables. If you don't want this, define variables instead of a map in the first place.

But I'm guessing what you really want is a way to access map values. Try this:

```
map-get($colors, blue)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you suggest that I take on a different strategy? I want one place where I can put my color palette. And reference it whenever I need to.